# Entity Manager with Sharepoint

Tags: 2013, visual-studio-2013

I'm quite new to the Sharepoint universe and this might be a stupid question but anyway here's my problem

Long story short : I have an application to make and in it I will have to manage entities (probably hosted on a SQL server).

I already did some work with an MVC framework (Symfony 2) and I wonder if there is something like Symfony's Doctrine in Sharepoint to manage the entity (relationship, CRUD operations etc..)

(The application will most likely be created with the Provider-Hosted solution)

Answer (score -1):

There is no Out of box ORM tool for Sharepoint. And for Provider hosted you need to use Client Object model. You can create you Entity classes and use CSOM for various CRUD operations.

Comment: How about making the SQL data visible for the application ? Does it have to be with BDC?

Comment: You can perform CRUD on SharePoint using  SQL directly. It is not supported at all.

Comment: Hum yeah but accessing directly Sharepoint databases is pretty ugly, and the application data will be located elsewhere, probably another server of the farm

Comment: Oops, typo mistake.. You can not perform CRUD on SharePoint using SQL directly. It is not supported at all.

Comment: Oh ok well yeah, but I meant access the entity (stored in SQL)

Comment: What type of entity? Not related to sharepoint?

Comment: No a complete external database schemas to be used in sharepoint

Comment: i don't understand external database to be used in sharepoint

Comment: Well in fact it's going to be a Web application, but the IT team want to put it into sharepoint to be able to use the user and the group system (even if it's going to be with FBA and not with the AD)